# How to pass keyword arguments to another method or class in python?

Tags: python, arguments, keyword-argument

I'm running into something strange as I'm reading someone's code and trying to make use of it.

I need to instantiate a class they wrote.  I was looking at their example which is currently being run in production so me mimicking it should be working correctly.  Anyway, in their code, I see them passing a kwarg dict to the class.  I try to do the same thing in my code, however, when I step thru the code with pdb, my kwargs is empty.  Perhaps I'm missing a very simple concept but I can't understand why it works for them and not for me.

Please excuse any errors from sanitizing the code.

This is their class I am trying to instantiate from my code

```
class MainConsumer(theading.Thread):
   def __init__(self, varA, varB, varC=None, varD=None, **kwargs):
      self.varA = varA
      self.varB = varB
      self.varC = varC
      self.varD = varD
      self.kwargs = kwargs  # I am checking here in pdb and apparently it's empty
```

This is my code calling their MainConsumer code, which doesn't appear to be passing extra_args to their class/code.  My code is very similar to their code when they instantiate their MainConsumer.

```
class MyTestConsumer(object):
   def __init__(self, varA, varB, varC, varD=None, varE=None):
      self.varA = varA
      self.varB = varB
      extra_args = dict(varC=varC, varD=varD, varE=varE) 

      self.some_consumer = MainConsumer(varA, varB, **extra_args) # checked here in pdb and extra_args has a dict of the variables from above
```

Apparently it's working this way for them.  They are able to pass extra_args to MainConsumer and the kwargs == extra_args.
Why is kwargs empty when I check on it after it was instantiated in MyTestConsumer?  Am I passing extra_args correctly when instantiating MainConsumer?  I made sure my vars were not None but maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: When I run your code and instantiate a `MyTestConsumer` I see `varE` in `MainConsumer`'s `kwargs` variable.

Comment: I've tested the code and it seems fine. The `self.kwargs` and `kwargs` from the `MainConsumer` class are behaving as expected. Can you show how are you instantiating the `MyTestConsumer` class and what is the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

What do you think about subclass

```
class MainConsumer(theading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, varA, varB, varC=None, varD=None, **kwargs):
        self.varA = varA
        self.varB = varB
        self.varC = varC
        self.varD = varD
        self.kwargs = kwargs

class MyTestConsumer(MainConsumer):
    def __init__(self, varA, varB, varC, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(varA, varB, varC, **kwargs)
# ----------------------------------------------------

mtc = MyTestConsumer(10, 20, varC=30, varE=50, boat=100, Mermaid=200)

print(mtc.varA, mtc.varB, mtc.varC, mtc.varD, mtc.kwargs)
```